# Crash on focus UITextField

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone

I am working on an iOS app, but for some reason all of a sudden my login page is not working anymore. All of the UIElements seem to be working fine except for the UITextField I use for the username (Password textField is working fine).

The login screen is very basic, it has a one viewcontroller and the username textfield has one outlet in that viewcontroller.

I don't do anything with the textfield when it focuses.
It happens on iOS8 on the physical iPad 2, and on the iPhone 4s emulator.

What I have tried to do:

- Re-install the app
- Re-ad the textField
- Re-connect the Outlet
- Revert my storyboard to a working version

I found some other answers, but none of them seem to have a conclusive answer.

Exception:

```
2015-03-24 11:13:53.695 App[43084:866627] -[__NSCFString objectAtIndex:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x7ae5f920
2015-03-24 11:13:53.726 App[43084:866627] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[__NSCFString objectAtIndex:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x7ae5f920'
*** First throw call stack:
(
    0   CoreFoundation                      0x00def466 __exceptionPreprocess + 182
    1   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x006d7a97 objc_exception_throw + 44
    2   CoreFoundation                      0x00df72c5 -[NSObject(NSObject) doesNotRecognizeSelector:] + 277
    3   CoreFoundation                      0x00d3fbc7 ___forwarding___ + 1047
    4   CoreFoundation                      0x00d3f78e _CF_forwarding_prep_0 + 14
    5   CoreFoundation                      0x00cc531c CFArrayGetValueAtIndex + 188
    6   CoreFoundation                      0x00d601ed CFStringTokenizerCreate + 749
    7   UIKit                               0x01c377ce __91-[_UITextInputControllerTokenizer _getClosestTokenRangeForPosition:granularity:downstream:]_block_invoke44 + 264
    8   UIFoundation                        0x0439e9d3 -[NSTextStorage coordinateReading:] + 51
    9   UIKit                               0x01c37459 -[_UITextInputControllerTokenizer _getClosestTokenRangeForPosition:granularity:downstream:] + 276
    10  UIKit                               0x018ba567 -[UITextInputStringTokenizer positionFromPosition:toBoundary:inDirection:] + 93
    11  UIKit                               0x018bad9d -[TIDocumentState(UITextInputAdditions) _contextBeforePosition:inDocument:] + 81
    12  UIKit                               0x018baef3 -[TIDocumentState(UITextInputAdditions) initWithDocument:] + 125
    13  UIKit                               0x018ba95f +[TIDocumentState(UITextInputAdditions) documentStateOfDocument:] + 63
    14  UIKit                               0x015fad7b -[UIKeyboardImpl syncDocumentStateToInputDelegateWithExecutionContext:] + 298
    15  UIKit                               0x015fb787 -[UIKeyboardImpl updateForChangedSelectionWithExecutionContext:] + 326
    16  UIKit                               0x015f57b6 __36-[UIKeyboardImpl setDelegate:force:]_block_invoke + 43
    17  UIKit                               0x01c384b2 -[UIKeyboardTaskQueue continueExecutionOnMainThread] + 404
    18  UIKit                               0x01c38b6f -[UIKeyboardTaskQueue addTask:] + 144
    19  UIKit                               0x015f5783 -[UIKeyboardImpl setDelegate:force:] + 2450
    20  UIKit                               0x015f4dec -[UIKeyboardImpl setDelegate:] + 60
    21  UIKit                               0x01928fe5 -[UIPeripheralHost(UIKitInternal) _reloadInputViewsForResponder:] + 1096
    22  UIKit                               0x01570687 -[UIResponder(UIResponderInputViewAdditions) reloadInputViews] + 316
    23  UIKit                               0x0156f6ec -[UIResponder becomeFirstResponder] + 562
    24  UIKit                               0x01435ba0 -[UIView(Hierarchy) becomeFirstResponder] + 114
    25  UIKit                               0x01c04607 -[UITextField becomeFirstResponder] + 51
    26  UIKit                               0x018051bf -[UITextInteractionAssistant(UITextInteractionAssistant_Internal) setFirstResponderIfNecessary] + 200
    27  UIKit                               0x018077e6 -[UITextInteractionAssistant(UITextInteractionAssistant_Internal) oneFingerTap:] + 2762
    28  UIKit                               0x017fb057 _UIGestureRecognizerSendActions + 327
    29  UIKit                               0x017f98d4 -[UIGestureRecognizer _updateGestureWithEvent:buttonEvent:] + 561
    30  UIKit                               0x017fb91d -[UIGestureRecognizer _delayedUpdateGesture] + 60
    31  UIKit                               0x017ff29a ___UIGestureRecognizerUpdate_block_invoke661 + 57
    32  UIKit                               0x017ff15d _UIGestureRecognizerRemoveObjectsFromArrayAndApplyBlocks + 317
    33  UIKit                               0x017f3066 _UIGestureRecognizerUpdate + 3720
    34  UIKit                               0x0140ac5b -[UIWindow _sendGesturesForEvent:] + 1356
    35  UIKit                               0x0140babf -[UIWindow sendEvent:] + 769
    36  UIKit                               0x013d0bb1 -[UIApplication sendEvent:] + 242
    37  UIKit                               0x013e0bf6 _UIApplicationHandleEventFromQueueEvent + 21066
    38  UIKit                               0x013b4bc7 _UIApplicationHandleEventQueue + 2300
    39  CoreFoundation                      0x00d1298f __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_SOURCE0_PERFORM_FUNCTION__ + 15
    40  CoreFoundation                      0x00d0849d __CFRunLoopDoSources0 + 253
    41  CoreFoundation                      0x00d079f8 __CFRunLoopRun + 952
    42  CoreFoundation                      0x00d0737b CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 443
    43  CoreFoundation                      0x00d071ab CFRunLoopRunInMode + 123
    44  GraphicsServices                    0x04e182c1 GSEventRunModal + 192
    45  GraphicsServices                    0x04e180fe GSEventRun + 104
    46  UIKit                               0x013b89b6 UIApplicationMain + 1526
    47  App                              0x0005ffbd main + 141
    48  libdyld.dylib                       0x0296dac9 start + 1
    49  ???                                 0x00000001 0x0 + 1
)
libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException
```

Viewcontroller:

```
#import "LoginViewController.h"

@implementation LoginViewController

UserManager *usermanager;

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
}
- (IBAction)cancelLogin:(id)sender {
    [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:true completion:nil];
}

- (IBAction)login:(id)sender {
    [loginIndicator startAnimating];
    LoginHandler *loginhandler = [[LoginHandler alloc]initWithUsername:usernameField.text
                                                              password:passwordField.text
                                                                  beta:betaSwitch.isOn
                                                                  view:self];
    [loginhandler loginUser];
}

-(void)resetFields{
    usernameField.text = @"";
    passwordField.text = @"";
    [loginIndicator stopAnimating];
}

@end
```

Viewcontroller.h

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
#import "LoginHandler.h"

@interface LoginViewController : UIViewController{


    __weak IBOutlet UITextField *usernameField;
    __weak IBOutlet UITextField *passwordField;
    __weak IBOutlet UIActivityIndicatorView *loginIndicator;
    __weak IBOutlet UISwitch *betaSwitch;
    __weak IBOutlet UINavigationBar *navigationBar;
}

-(void)resetFields;

@end
```

An exception breakpoint gives this line:

```
2015-03-24 11:43:41.338 App[323:15867] -[__NSCFString objectAtIndex:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x15653690
```

Can anyone else help me?
Thanks

Comment: Does it crash while debugging? If yes you should see error message in console on crash - it is usually very helpful

Comment: You are right, totally forgot to add it

Comment: Try to find the line. It seems that you're manipulating a `NSString` like it was a `NSArray`.

Comment: Show some code So then I will easily help you ?

Comment: The problem is, the error seems to occur before any of my code is executed, only a viewDidLoad which only calls the super

Comment: Are you getting the value from textfield from it's "text" property ?

Comment: Yeah, but only after the login button is clicked

Comment: Add an exception breakpoint and see that line it crashes on.

Comment: But which line in your code causes the crash?

Comment: That's the problem, I am not sure. I added the line an exception breakpoint gives me.

Comment: Also, if I change it to a secure text entry, it does work normally

Comment: i Think you should check the code for Loginhandler

Comment: The exception occurs before the LoginHandler is called, so that seems very unlikely

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I seem to have found an answer, it had something to do with my constraints for some reason. I cleared the constraints and re-added them and somehow it is working again.